# Is there any caching enabled setting at F5 loadbalancer level?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7.5, f5

I have a single webserver for my application, where I deploy the code. The webserver is linked with F5 loadbalancer.
I have deployed the latest code twice on the webserver and also validated the code by manual checking. I also cross checked the database entries on the database server (SQL SERVER 2012) and found all fine.
After deployment completed, I started testing the changes from my local machine and then I started seeing some weird behavior of the application. I am still seeing some pages which are not affected as part of new deployment code changes.
As part of troubleshooting I did ApplicationPool Recycling, IIS Reset but still I see the same old pages.
I now have a doubt on the F5 loadbalancer settings. Can anyone help me to know is there any possibility that due to caching enabled at F5 loadbalancer level I am still seeing the same old pages?

Thanks & Regards,
Santosh Kumar Patro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no caching enabled vy default for F5 LTM's unless the Web Accelerator module is also provisioned in which caching will take effect.